# Swift Dictionary access value using key within extension

Tags: swift, dictionary, hashtable, extension-methods, subscript

It turns out that within a Dictionary extension, the subscript is quite useless since it says `Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'`. It seems I'll either have to do what Swift does in its `subscript(Key)` or call a function. Any ideas?

For example,

```
public extension Dictionary {
    public func bool(_ key: String) -> Bool? {
        return self[key] as? Bool
    }
}
```

won't work, since the subscript is said to be ambiguous.

**ADDED** My misunderstanding came from the fact that I assumed that `Key` is an `AssociatedType` instead of a generic parameter.

Comment: There you go, now people have something to go off

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I honestly don't think the sample code is different from what I explained, but I guess it makes the question easier to grasp.

Comment: It eliminates the guess work, and saves us from wasting the time of making a comparable test setup

Comment: Also, keep it mind that very often we see people coming here with an issue, describe their code as they think it is, and after some tedious back and forth, we find out it's not actually so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift type `Dictionary` has two generic parameters `Key` and `Value`, and `Key` may not be `String`.

This works:

```
public extension Dictionary {
    public func bool(_ key: Key) -> Bool? {
        return self[key] as? Bool
    }
}

let dict: [String: Any] = [
    "a": true,
    "b": 0,
]
if let a = dict.bool("a") {
    print(a) //->true
}
if let b = dict.bool("b") {
    print(b) //not executed
}
```

---

For **ADDED** part.

If you introduce a new generic parameter `T` in extension of `Dictionary`, the method **needs to work for all possible combination** of `Key`(`:Hashable`), `Value` and `T`(`:Hashable`). `Key` and `T` may not be the same type.

(For example, `Key` may be `String` and `T` may be `Int` (both `Hashable`). You know you cannot subscript with `Int` when `Key` is `String`.)

So, you cannot subscript with `key` of type `T`.

---

For updated **ADDED** part.

Seems to be a reasonable misunderstanding. And you have found a good example that explains protocol with associated type is not just a generic protocol.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That's why the return type is `Bool?` in the first place. For instance `var dic: [AnyHashable: Any] = ["1": 1]; print(dic[1])` gives a `nil`. The `Key` must be `Hashable`, which `String` conforms to.

Comment: So what? `String` conforms to `Hashable` does not mean `Key` is always `String`.

Comment: Well my function specifies that the key is always `String`.

Comment: So why isn't it working? `Key: Hashable` is what the Dictionary asks for. The function's parameter is strictly contrained to `String`, which is `Hashable`.

Comment: `Dictionary`'s `Key` is a `Hashable` but not necessarily `String`.  i.e. `self[String]` won't be right if the `Key` is some other `Hashable`.

Comment: You are writing an extension for general `Dictionary`, not for `Dictionary<String, SomeType>`. The dictionary may accept `String` or may not accept `String`. How does your extension work for `[Int: Int]`?

Comment: It doesn't work for `public extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral` either. I've already tried.

Comment: `Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral` does not mean `Key` is always `String`. It just express that `Key` is initializable using string literal, you can make `Int` conform to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, but `Int` is not `String`.

Comment: Although your answer does solve the problem I have, the problem lies in the fact that `String` could apply for both `Key` and `Value` since `Key: Hashable` and `Value: Any` which `String` both applies to; hence the ambiguity.

Comment: When writing an extension for general `Dictionary` (without specifying any constraints), the extension needs to work all possible combination of `Key` (`: Hashable`) and `Value`. _ambiguous_ is not a good diagnostics here, it should just say **this extension does not work**.