# Returning Value from Dictionary subscript method

Tags: swift

I am using some new features of Swift 4 programming language. For some reason it is complaining in the below code where I am returning the self[key] value.

```
extension Dictionary {

    subscript<T>(key :String, type :T) -> T? {
        get {
            return self[key] as? T // this line
        }
    }
}
```

> MyPlayground.playground:1:5: note: found this candidate
>
> ```
> subscript<T>(key :String, type :T) -> T? {
> ```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

```
extension Dictionary {

    subscript<T>(key :Key) -> T? {
        return self[key] as? T
    }
}

struct Pokemon {
    var title :String
}

let pokemon = Pokemon(title: "Pikachu")

var dictionary = [String:Any]()
dictionary["foo"] = "hello world"
dictionary["pokemon"] = pokemon

let p = dictionary["pokemon"] // this calls the default subscript not mine
```

Comment: Not all dictionaries have `String` keys ;)

Comment: Thats true! But am I not creating a different subscript function which has String as a key.

Comment: But the subscript you're trying to implement takes a `String` key – you meant `Key`.

Comment: Compare [Swift Dictionary access value using key within extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41133595/2976878). Also you probably meant for the `type` parameter to take a `T.Type`.

Comment: Also even though I have the subscript property added as an extension when I use dictionary it always uses the default implementation. Any way to change that to pick my implementation of subscript

Comment: I'm not running Swift 4, so cannot test, but I don't see what other subscript could be called for `dict[someKey, someType]` – are you sure that's how you're calling it?

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: If you explicitly annotate `p` as something other than `Any`, your subscript should be called. But really that's quite an unclear addition to the dictionary API, I would keep it with an explicit `type:` parameter. Also I *suspect* that your implementation of the subscript will infinitely recurse.

Comment: Basically they added support for Generic Type Subscripts.